# laradock error on phpmyadmin - can't connect

Tags: laravel, docker, phpmyadmin, laradock

I just started using docker, laradock and laravel, after setting up the entire environment I tried to login on my phpmyadmin and I couldn't sign in.

I looked pretty much everywhere and couldn't find a way to fix it so you guys are my last hope lol.

**Docker version** 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
Here's my docker ps
[image: docker ps]

**My project's .env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

And here are the errors I am getting from phpmyadmin (localhost:8080)

```
#2054 - The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile(s) and the command that you use to up and link your containers?
Help more with this information.

Comment: the command I used to up was

docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin

I created a laravel project with this command  
docker-compose exec workspace bash
compose create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectname

Comment: @CarlosEduardo I am new with docker and laradock so I am not sure what Dockerfiles you're asking for

Comment: Based in your commands I believe the answer from @Alex Karshin is the way to solve your question.

Comment: change DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

Comment: @CarlosEduardo yeah, so I was wrong after all, hah. Gil Penner I suggest  you stop posting template files and just post your real configuration. Noone is going to scroll through 700+ lines of templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to revert back to an earlier version of MySQL. It's probably a good idea anyway since 8.0 is a "developer's release". Unfortunately Laradock currently has a bug that installs 8.0 no matter what you set in the .env file. I've submitted a PR on Laradock to fix this particular issue.

https://github.com/laradock/laradock/pull/1409

Comment: That could be it, I gave up installing docker and laradock on Windows.
Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score -1):

This is caused by an update to `libmysqlclient` since [MySQL version 8.0.4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-4.html#mysqld-8-0-4-security) which has changed the default authentication method to a more secure `sha256_password`.

As soon as Laravel and other software packages such as PhpMyAdmin are updated to support this new and more secure authentication method this problem wil resolve itself.

If you **CANNOT** delete and rebuild your existing mysql data volume, simply:

1. Sign in to your mysql container (`docker-compose exec mysql mysql -uroot -proot`)
2. Execute `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';`
3. Repeat step 2 for any other users you may have created.

If you **CAN** recreate your mysql data volume:

1. Modify your `my.conf` file. Under `[mysqld]` add the following configuration option `default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password`
2. Delete your mysql volume `rm -rf ~./laradock/data/mysql`
3. Rebuild the mysql container `docker-compose -d --build mysql phpmyadmin`